# Custom dataset with YOLOv7, assertion error. Label class 1 exceeds nc=1

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, google-colaboratory, object-detection, yolov7

I want to train the YOLOv7 with a custom dataset, the dataset is from COCO, but I want to train it only for sheep class.
I have in the **coco.yaml** file:

```
path: /content/drive/MyDrive/Sheep/yolov7
train: data/train/images
val: data/val/images 
test: data/val/images
nc=1
names: [ 'sheep' ]
```

In **yolov7.yaml** I have also set the number of classes to 1:

```
nc: 1  # number of classes
depth_multiple: 1.0  # model depth multiple
width_multiple: 1.0  # layer channel multiple
...
```

When I want to train the model in Colab,  I get an error saying: `assert mlc < nc, 'Label class %g exceeds nc=%g in %s. Possible class labels are 0-%g' % (mlc, nc, opt.data, nc - 1) AssertionError: Label class 1 exceeds nc=1 in data/coco.yaml. Possible class labels are 0-0`

I understood that the labels have to start from 0, because i have `nc=1` so I changed in every .txt file the labels to `0` where sheep are detected. I don't have any other class in the label's files. Here's an example of a label .txt file:

```
0 0.2 0.6652267818574514 0.05 0.11231101511879049
0 0.346875 0.6965442764578834 0.046875 0.1101511879049676
0 0.4578125 0.6889848812095032 0.040625 0.12095032397408208
0 0.49140625 0.6987041036717062 0.0515625 0.1101511879049676
0 0.553125 0.6922246220302376 0.05625 0.11447084233261338
0 0.5859375 0.6695464362850972 0.04375 0.07775377969762419
0 0.2890625 0.6781857451403888 0.034375 0.12095032397408208
```

Do I need to change anything in **train.py** ? I left the code as it was in https://github.com/WongKinYiu/yolov7

I'm new to machine learning so please help me solve this. Thank you!